# A semantics for Bash scripts?

Tags: bash

More than any other language I know, I've "learned" Bash by Googling every time I need some little thing. Consequently, I can patchwork together little scripts that appear to work. However, I don't *really* know what's going on, and I was hoping for a more formal introduction to Bash as a programming language. For example: What is the evaluation order? what are the scoping rules? What is the typing discipline, e.g. is everything a string? What is the state of the program -- is it a key-value assignment of strings to variable names; is there more than that, e.g. the stack? Is there a heap? And so on.

I thought to consult the GNU Bash manual for this kind of insight, but it doesn't seem to be what I want; it's more of a laundry list of syntactic sugar rather than an explanation of the core semantic model. The million-and-one "bash tutorials" online are only worse. Perhaps I should first study `sh`, and understand Bash as a syntactic sugar on top of this? I don't know if this is an accurate model, though.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I've been asked to provide examples of what ideally I'm looking for. A rather extreme example of what I would consider a "formal semantics" is [this paper on "the essence of JavaScript"](http://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Papers/Published/gsk-essence-javascript/paper.pdf). Perhaps a slightly less formal example is the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf).

Comment: Is the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) one of the "million and one"?

Comment: I still _love_ Kernighan and Pike's _The Unix Programming Environment_. It's one of those books. It explains sh and the other unix utilities in context and cooperation and is not outdated because the basics didn't really change. Get it and enjoy.

Comment: I'm not convinced that bash has a "core semantic model" (well, maybe "almost everything is a string"); i think it's really syntactic sugar all the way down.

Comment: What you call "a laundry list of syntactic sugar" is actually the semantic model of expansion -- an extremely important part of execution. 90% of bugs and confusion is due to not understanding the expansion model.

Comment: I can see why someone might think this is a broad question if you read it like *how do I write a shell script*? But the real question is *what are the formal semantics and basis for shell language and bash in particular?*, and it is a good question with a single coherent answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I learned quite a bit on linuxcommand.org and there is even a free pdf of a more in-depth book on the command line *and* writing shell scripts

Comment: I think this may be asking a lot of `bash`. I don't think a shell is as rigorously thought out as a language semantics as other programming languages are. It's a more frequently barnacled set of capabilities accumulated over time. One could probably look back on it at any given time and try to capture it's current capability set as a semantic model, but it's probably not been worth anyone's time to do so.

Comment: @thatotherguy I think you're right that sugar is more important in Bash than in many other languages. But traditionally there's a clear separation between *expansion* and *execution* in a semantics. I'd like something that clearly distinguishes those -- e.g., starts by describing the "micro-Bash" language that remains after all expansion takes place.

Comment: @lurker the same is true of other languages that people have attempted to create formal models for; what they often do is target a small core of the language, without a lot of the barnacles.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

A shell is an interface for the operating system. It is usually a more-or-less robust programming language in its own right, but with features designed to make it easy to interact specifically with the operating system and filesystem. The POSIX shell's (hereafter referred to just as "the shell") semantics are a bit of a mutt, combining some features of LISP (s-expressions have a lot in common with shell [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)) and C (much of the shell's [arithmetic syntax](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) semantics comes from C).

The other root of the shell's syntax comes from its upbringing as a mishmash of individual UNIX utilities. Most of what are often builtins in the shell can actually be implemented as external commands. It throws many shell neophytes for a loop when they realize that `/bin/[` exists on many systems.

```
$ if '/bin/[' -f '/bin/['; then echo t; fi # Tested as-is on OS X, without the `]`
t
```

wat?

This makes a lot more sense if you look at how a shell is implemented. Here's an implementation I did as an exercise. It's in Python, but I hope that's not a hangup for anyone. It's not terribly robust, but it is instructive:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys

'''Hacky barebones shell.'''

try:
  input=raw_input
except NameError:
  pass

def main():
  while True:
    cmd = input('prompt> ')
    args = cmd.split()
    if not args:
      continue
    cpid = os.fork()
    if cpid == 0:
      # We're in a child process
      os.execl(args[0], *args)
    else:
      os.waitpid(cpid, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I hope the above makes it clear that the execution model of a shell is pretty much:

```
1. Expand words.
2. Assume the first word is a command.
3. Execute that command with the following words as arguments.
```

Expansion, command resolution, execution. All of the shell's semantics are bound up in one of these three things, although they're far richer than the implementation I wrote above.

Not all commands `fork`. In fact, there are a handful of commands that don't make [a ton of sense](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command) implemented as externals (such that they would have to `fork`), but even those are often available as externals for strict POSIX compliance.

Bash builds upon this base by adding new features and keywords to enhance the POSIX shell. It is nearly compatible with sh, and bash is so ubiquitous that some script authors go years without realizing that a script may not actually work on a POSIXly strict system. (I also wonder how people can care so much about the semantics and style of one programming language, and so little for the semantics and style of the shell, but I diverge.)

### Order of evaluation

This is a bit of a trick question: Bash interprets expressions in its primary syntax from left to right, but in its arithmetic syntax it follows C precedence. Expressions differ from *expansions*, though. From the `EXPANSION` section of the bash manual:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter
>     and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution
>     (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

If you understand wordsplitting, pathname expansion and parameter expansion, you are well on your way to understanding most of what bash does. Note that pathname expansion coming after wordsplitting is critical, because it ensures that a file with whitespace in its name can still be matched by a glob. This is why good use of glob expansions is better than [parsing commands](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), in general.

### Scope

#### Function scope

Much like old ECMAscript, the shell has dynamic scope unless you explicitly declare names within a function.

```
$ foo() { echo $x; }
$ bar() { local x; echo $x; }
$ foo

$ bar

$ x=123
$ foo
123
$ bar

$ …
```

#### Environment and process "scope"

Subshells inherit the variables of their parent shells, but other kinds of processes don't inherit unexported names.

```
$ x=123
$ ( echo $x )
123
$ bash -c 'echo $x'

$ export x
$ bash -c 'echo $x'
123
$ y=123 bash -c 'echo $y' # another way to transiently export a name
123
```

You can combine these scoping rules:

```
$ foo() {
>   local -x bar=123 # Export foo, but only in this scope
>   bash -c 'echo $bar'
> }
$ foo
123
$ echo $bar

$
```

### Typing discipline

Um, types. Yeah. Bash really doesn't have types, and everything expands to a string (or perhaps a *word* would be more appropriate.) But let's examine the different types of expansions.

#### Strings

Pretty much anything can be treated as a string. Barewords in bash are strings whose meaning depends entirely on the expansion applied to it.

No expansion

It may be worthwhile to demonstrate that a bare word really is just a word, and that quotes change nothing about that.

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ 'echo' foo
foo
$ "echo" foo
foo
```

Substring expansion

```
$ fail='echoes'
$ set -x # So we can see what's going on
$ "${fail:0:-2}" Hello World
+ echo Hello World
Hello World
```

For more on expansions, read the `Parameter Expansion` section of the manual. It's quite powerful.

#### Integers and arithmetic expressions

You can imbue names with the integer attribute to tell the shell to treat the right hand side of assignment expressions as arithmetic. Then, when the parameter expands it will be evaluated as integer math before expanding to … a string.

```
$ foo=10+10
$ echo $foo
10+10
$ declare -i foo
$ foo=$foo # Must re-evaluate the assignment
$ echo $foo
20
$ echo "${foo:0:1}" # Still just a string
2
```

#### Arrays

Arguments and Positional Parameters

Before talking about arrays it might be worth discussing positional parameters. The arguments to a shell script can be accessed using numbered parameters, `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. You can access all these parameters at once using `"$@"`, which expansion has many things in common with arrays. You can set and change the positional parameters using the `set` or `shift` builtins, or simply by invoking the shell or a shell function with these parameters:

```
$ bash -c 'for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)); do
>   printf "\$%d => %s\n" "$i" "${@:i:1}"
> done' -- foo bar baz
$1 => foo
$2 => bar
$3 => baz
$ showpp() {
>   local i
>   for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)); do
>     printf '$%d => %s\n' "$i" "${@:i:1}"
>   done
> }
$ showpp foo bar baz
$1 => foo
$2 => bar
$3 => baz
$ showshift() {
>   shift 3
>   showpp "$@"
> }
$ showshift foo bar baz biz quux xyzzy
$1 => biz
$2 => quux
$3 => xyzzy
```

The bash manual also sometimes refers to `$0` as a positional parameter. I find this confusing, because it doesn't include it in the argument count `$#`, but it is a numbered parameter, so meh. `$0` is the name of the shell or the current shell script.

Arrays

The syntax of arrays is modeled after positional parameters, so it's mostly healthy to think of arrays as a named kind of "external positional parameters", if you like. Arrays can be declared using the following approaches:

```
$ foo=( element0 element1 element2 )
$ bar[3]=element3
$ baz=( [12]=element12 [0]=element0 )
```

You can access array elements by index:

```
$ echo "${foo[1]}"
element1
```

You can slice arrays:

```
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${foo[@]:1}"
"element1"
"element2"
```

If you treat an array as a normal parameter, you'll get the zeroth index.

```
$ echo "$baz"
element0
$ echo "$bar" # Even if the zeroth index isn't set

$ …
```

If you use quotes or backslashes to prevent wordsplitting, the array will maintain the specified wordsplitting:

```
$ foo=( 'elementa b c' 'd e f' )
$ echo "${#foo[@]}"
2
```

The main difference between arrays and positional parameters are:

1. Positional parameters are not sparse. If `$12` is set, you can be sure `$11` is set, too. (It could be set to the empty string, but `$#` will not be smaller than 12.) If `"${arr[12]}"` is set, there's no guarantee that `"${arr[11]}"` is set, and the length of the array could be as small as 1.
2. The zeroth element of an array is unambiguously the zeroth element of that array. In positional parameters, the zeroth element is not the *first argument*, but the name of the shell or shell script.
3. To `shift` an array, you have to slice and reassign it, like `arr=( "${arr[@]:1}" )`. You could also do `unset arr[0]`, but that would make the first element at index 1.
4. Arrays can be shared implicitly between shell functions as globals, but you have to explicitly pass positional parameters to a shell function for it to see those.

It's often convenient to use pathname expansions to create arrays of filenames:

```
$ dirs=( */ )
```

#### Commands

Commands are key, but they're also covered in better depth than I can by the manual. Read the `SHELL GRAMMAR` section. The different kinds of commands are:

1. Simple Commands (e.g. `$ startx`)
2. Pipelines (e.g. `$ yes | make config`) (lol)
3. Lists (e.g. `$ grep -qF foo file && sed 's/foo/bar/' file > newfile`)
4. Compound Commands (e.g. `$ ( cd -P /var/www/webroot && echo "webroot is $PWD" )`)
5. Coprocesses (Complex, no example)
6. Functions (A named compound command that can be treated as a simple command)

### Execution Model

The execution model of course involves both a heap and a stack. This is endemic to all UNIX programs. Bash also has a call stack for shell functions, visible via nested use of the `caller` builtin.

References:

1. The `SHELL GRAMMAR` section of the bash manual
2. The [XCU Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) documentation
3. The [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) on Greycat's wiki.
4. [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.apuebook.com/)

Please make comments if you want me to expand further in a specific direction.

Comment: +1: Great explanation. Appreciate the time spent on writing this with examples.

Comment: +1 for `yes | make config` ;-)  But seriously, a very good write-up.

Comment: just started to read this.. nice. will leave some comments. 1) an even bigger surprise comes when you see that `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` is often the same applicaton 2) "Assume the first word is a command." - expect when you do assignment...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, I intentionally excluded assignment from my demo shell because variables are a complicated mess. That demo shell was not written with this answer in mind – it was written much earlier. I suppose I could make it `execle` and interpolate the first words into the environment, but that would still make it quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: @kojiro: nah that would just over-complicate it, that certainly wasn't my intention! but assignment works a bit differently(x), and IMHO you should mention it somewhere in text. (x): and a source of some confusion... I cannot even count anymore how many times did I see people complaing about `a = 1` not working).

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about how to better fit variable assignment expressions into the write up.

Comment: By far the best answer here. I should say, though, that while this does answer the questions in my list, the list I presented was a "for example", and I'm still looking for a paper that gives a coherent, comprehensive semantic model. If anyone were to come forward with something like that, I would change my accepted answer. Til then, this is good. :-)

Comment: @jameshfisher would you please update your question with an example of a comprehensive semantic model from another programming language?

Comment: @kojiro sure thing, have done. Oh and please don't take my comment as criticism; yours is a useful post in its own right regardless of what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question "What is the typing discipline, e.g. is everything a string" 
Bash variables are character strings. But, Bash permits arithmetic operations and comparisons on variables when variables are integers. The exception to rule Bash variables are character strings is when said variables are typeset or declared otherwise

```
$ A=10/2
$ echo "A = $A"           # Variable A acting like a String.
A = 10/2

$ B=1
$ let B="$B+1"            # Let is internal to bash.
$ echo "B = $B"           # One is added to B was Behaving as an integer.
B = 2

$ A=1024                  # A Defaults to string
$ B=${A/24/STRING01}      # Substitute "24"  with "STRING01".
$ echo "B = $B"           # $B STRING is a string
B = 10STRING01

$ B=${A/24/STRING01}      # Substitute "24"  with "STRING01".
$ declare -i B
$ echo "B = $B"           # Declaring a variable with non-integers in it doesn't change the contents.
B = 10STRING01

$ B=${B/STRING01/24}      # Substitute "STRING01"  with "24".
$ echo "B = $B"
B = 1024

$ declare -i B=10/2       # Declare B and assigning it an integer value
$ echo "B = $B"           # Variable B behaving as an Integer
B = 5
```

Declare option meanings:

- -a   Variable is an array.
- -f   Use function names only.
- -i   The variable is to be treated as an integer; arithmetic evaluation is performed when the variable is assigned a value.
- -p   Display the attributes and values of each variable. When -p is used, additional options are ignored.
- -r   Make variables read-only. These variables cannot then be assigned values by subsequent assignment statements, nor can they be unset.
- -t   Give each variable the trace attribute.
- -x   Mark each variable for export to subsequent commands via the environment.

Answer (score 1):

The bash manpage has quite a bit more info than most manpages, and includes some of what you're asking for.  My assumption after more than a decade of scripting bash is that, due to its' history as an extension of sh, it has some funky syntax (to maintain backward compatibility with sh).

FWIW, my experience has been like yours; although the various books (e.g., O'Reilly "Learning the Bash Shell" and similar) do help with the syntax, there are lots of strange ways of solving various problems, and some of them are not in the book and must be googled.