# How to properly process and print files with spaces in bash

Tags: bash, shell, ls, ifs, m

I'm writing a simple recursive ls program in bash (which I'm very not experienced at, so feel free to be brutal).

The program is supposed to print out each file (possibly directory) on a separate line, and each time a new directory is entered, the output is shifted over by 4 spaces, to give it a tree-like output.

Currently, it doesn't print out files with spaces correctly, and it doesn't put a forward slash after directories. (More details below.)

### Code

```sh
recls () {

    # store current working directory
    # issues: seems bad to have cwd defined up here and used down below in getAbsolutePath -- too much coupling
    cwd=$PWD
    # get absolute path of arg
    argdir=`getAbsolutePath "$@"`
    # check if it exists
    if [ ! -e $argdir ]; then
        echo "$argdir does not exist"
        return 1
    fi
    echo "$argdir exists"
    # check if it's a directory
    if [ ! -d $argdir ]; then
        echo "$argdir is not a directory"
        return 2
    fi
    echo "$argdir is a directory"
    tab=""
    recls_internal $argdir
    return 0

}

recls_internal () {

    for file in $@; do
        echo -n "$tab${file##/*/}"
        if [ -d $file ]; then
            # print forward slash to show it's a directory
            echo "/"
            savedtab=$tab
            tab="$tab    "
            myls_internal $file/*
            tab=$savedtab
        else
            # if not a directory, print a new line
            echo ""
        fi   
    done

}

getAbsolutePath () {

    if [ -z ${1##/*} ]; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        echo "$cwd/$1"
    fi

}
```

### Output

The script is contained in a folder called `bash-practice`. When I do `recls .`, I get the following output:

```
./
    myls.sh
    myls.sh~
    recdir.sh
    recls.sh
    recls.sh~
    sample
    document.txt
    sample-folder
        sample-stuff
            test-12.txt
        test-1.txt
        test-2.txt
        sort-test.txt
        sort-text-copy.txt
        test-5-19-14-1
```

### The Problem

As you can see, the indentation is working properly but there are two problems:

1) The file `sample document.txt` is spread across two lines, because it has a space in it.

2) Every directory should have a forward slash in front of it, but for some reason that only works on the very first one.

### Attempted Solution

In order to fix (1), I tried saving the internal file separator and replacing it with a newline character like so:

```sh
...
tab=""
savedIFS=$IFS
IFS="\n"
recls_internal $argdir
IFS=$savedIFS
return 0
```

But this did not work at all. It didn't even display more than the first folder. Clearly my understanding of things is not correct.

As for (2), I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be working as intended.

### Conclusion

bash is difficult for me as it seems to have more unusual syntax than most other programming languages (being a shell scripting language), so I would appreciate any insights into my mistakes, as well as a solution.

### Update #1

I went to the site http://www.shellcheck.com that mklement0 suggested, and its hints were basically all to double quote things more. When I double quoted `"$@"`, the program correctly printed the file `sample document.txt`, but then directly after that, it gave me a "`binary operator expected`" error. Here is a print out of what it looks like now:

[image]

### Update #2 [problem solved?]

OK, it turns out that I had a typo which was causing it to default to an earlier version of my function called `myls_internal` when it recursed. This earlier version didn't mark directories with a forward slash. The error message in the "Update" section was also fixed. I changed the line

> `myls_internal "$file/*"`

to

> `recls_internal $file/*`

and now it seems to work properly. If anyone is in the middle of writing an answer, I still appreciate your insights as I don't really understand the mechanics of how quoting "$@" fixed the spacing issue.

**Fixed code:**

```
recls () {

    # store current working directory
    # issues: seems bad to have cwd defined up here and used down below in getAbsolutePath -- too much coupling
    cwd=$PWD
    # get absolute path of arg
    argdir=$(getAbsolutePath "$@")
    # check if it exists
    if [ ! -e $argdir ]; then
        echo "$argdir does not exist"
        return 1
    fi
    echo "$argdir exists"
    # check if it's a directory
    if [ ! -d $argdir ]; then
        echo "$argdir is not a directory"
        return 2
    fi
    echo "$argdir is a directory"
    tab=""
    recls_internal $argdir
    return 0

}

recls_internal () {

    for file in "$@"; do
        echo -n "$tab${file##/*/}"
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            # print forward slash to show it's a directory
            echo "/"
            savedtab=$tab
            tab="$tab    "
            recls_internal $file/*
            tab=$savedtab
        else
            # if not a directory, print a new line
            echo ""
        fi   
    done

}

getAbsolutePath () {

    if [ -z ${1##/*} ]; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        echo "$cwd/$1"
    fi

}
```

**Fixed output:**

[image]

### Update #3

The line

> `recls_internal $file/*`

should instead be

> `recls_internal "$file"/*`

which handles directories with spaces in them correctly. Otherwise, a folder such as `cs 350` containing `Homework1.pdf` and `Homework2.pdf` will expand to

> `cs 350/Homework1.pdf 350/Homework2.pdf`

when it should be

> `cs 350/Homework1.pdf cs 350/Homework2.pdf`

I think? I don't really get the finer details of what's going on, but that seemed to fix it.

Comment: @rpax Didn't expect to see anyone to say that, thanks!

Comment: Paste your code at http://shellcheck.net - you'll get many tips re quoting and unwanted word splitting.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, I'll take a look at that. And if anyone else runs into this problem, I just fixed the issues with syntax highlighting in my post by specifying the language explicitly. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints?lq=1

Comment: That's a helpful hint regarding syntax highlighting, but note that the official post on that topic is now at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Bill I'm not actually parsing `ls`. You'll see that I never call anything but `echo` and my own function `recls`. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: One part of the answer is to ensure that file names and paths are enclosed in double quotes when expanded.  There are places where you can get away without using quotes, but you can 'always' use quotes and get the same result.  ('Always' in quotes because there's an exception for the regex operation of the `[[ ... ]]` built-in command.)

Comment: If, and only if, you don't actually *want to* write it yourself there is [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/).

Comment: I just edited my post with an update which seems to have fixed my problem. If anyone wants to give an answer still, I would appreciate the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the difference between `"$@"` and `$@`, let us consider the two following functions:

```
f() { for i in $@; do echo $i; done; }

g() { for i in "$@"; do echo $i; done; }
```

When calling these function with the parameters `a "b c" "d e"` the result will be

- function f

`f a "b c" "d e"
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e`

- function g

   `g a "b c" "d e"
   a
   b c
   d e`

So when "$@" is within double quotes, the expansion keeps each parameter in a separate word (even if the parameter contains one or more space).
When $@ (without double quotes) is expanded, a parameter with a space will be considered as two words.

In your script, you need also to surround `argdir` and `file` with double quotes. It is useful when the name of a directory or a file contains space so the name will be considered as a single value. Below your script modified.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -u
recls () {

    # store current working directory
    # issues: seems bad to have cwd defined up here and used down below in getAbsolutePath -- too much coupling
    cwd=$PWD
    # get absolute path of arg
    argdir=`getAbsolutePath "$@"`
    # check if it exists
    if [ ! -e "$argdir" ]; then
        echo "$argdir does not exist"
        return 1
    fi
    echo "$argdir exists"
    # check if it's a directory
    if [ ! -d "$argdir" ]; then
        echo "$argdir is not a directory"
        return 2
    fi
    echo "$argdir is a directory"
    tab=""
    recls_internal "$argdir"
    return 0

}

recls_internal () {

    for file in "$@"; do
        echo -n "$tab${file##/*/}"
        if [ -d "$file" ]; then
            # print forward slash to show it's a directory
            echo "/"
            savedtab=$tab
            tab="$tab    "
            recls_internal "$file"/*
            tab=$savedtab
        else
            # if not a directory, print a new line
            echo ""
        fi   
    done

}

getAbsolutePath () {

    if [ -z ${1##/*} ]; then
        echo "$1"
    else
        echo "$cwd/$1"
    fi

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clears up some of my confusion. I'm still a bit confused about globbing in general, but I found this meta-explanation of bash semantics which might help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207168/a-semantics-for-bash-scripts/23208014#23208014.