# bash difference between raw string and string in variable

Tags: string, bash, shell

I wrote a little script in bash, but it only worked when I stored the string as a variable, and I'd like to know why. Here's the summary:

When I use the string itself, bash treats it as a single entity

```
for word in "this is a sentence"; do
    echo $word
done
# => this is a sentence
```

If I save the exact same string into a variable, bash iterates over the words

```
sentence="this is a sentence"
for word in $sentence; do
    echo $word
done

# => this
# is
# a
# sentence
```

1. Why are these being treated differently?
2. Is there a simple way to iterate through the words in the string without first saving the string as a variable?

Comment: 1. Please learn about quotes.

Comment: 2. And try: `for word in this is a sentence; do echo "$word"; done`.

Comment: For clarity's sake, [shells don't really have data types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23208014/418413), so it's not too useful to call them "strings". (Disclaimer: it's my post, but it helps to understand how the shell differs from a programming language with data types. For a tl;dr, scroll down to the _Typing Discipline_ part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the assignment

```
sentence="this is a sentence"
```

there are no unquoted spaces, so everything to the right of the `=` is treated as a single word. (Something like `sentence=this is a sentence` would be parsed as a single assignment `sentence=this` followed by an attempt to run a program called `is`.) As a result, the value of `sentences` is a sequence of 18 characters. It is identical to

```
sentence=this\ is\ a\ sentence
```

because again, there are no unquoted spaces.

For the same reason

```
for word in "this is a sentence"; do
    echo $word
done
```

has `word` being set to each word in the following sequence, which only contains a single word because there are no unquoted spaces.

The key difference with your other loop is that parameter expansions are subject to word-splitting after the fact. The loop

```
for word in $sentence; do
    echo $word
done
```

after parameter expansion looks like

```
for word in this is a sentence; do
     echo $word
done
```

so now `word` is set to each of the *4* words in the list following the `in` keyword.

It's not clear what you are actually asking at the end of your question, but the preceding is legal code. There is no requirement that a string be placed in quotes in `bash`; quotes do not define something as a string value, but simply escape every character that appears within the quotes. `"foo"` and `\f\o\o` are the same thing in shell.

Answer (score 6):

The quotes tell bash to treat a thing in quotes as a single parameter in a parameter list *at the time the expression is evaluated*. The quotes (unless protected with \ or ') are removed.

```
echo ""    # prints newlines, no quotes
echo '""'  # Print ""

export X='""'
env | grep X   # X contains ""

export X=""
env | grep X   # X is empty
```

When you use a variable, bash unpacks it as is (i.e. as if you typed the variable's contents in the variable's place). For a for-loop bash determines the list-elements to iterate over by separating the for-loop's parameters by whitespace, but treating (as always) quote-protected items a single parameter/list-element. Your variable contained no quotes -- items are treated as separate parameters.

Answer (score 4):

As comments suggested, quotes are important.  A for loop will step through a list of values terminated by a semicolon, and that list is a set of strings.  Unquoted strings are delimited usually by whitespace.  Whitespace inside a quoted string does not separate the string from its brethren, it's simply part of the quoted string.  There's some truly excellent documentation about quotes in bash at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes .  Read it.  Read it now. You'll find a part that says

> The quotes are not actually passed along to the command. They are removed by the shell (this process is cleverly called "quote removal").

To step through the words in a sentence that's stored in a variable (if I've inferred your question correctly), you could perhaps use an array to separate the words by whitespace:

```
#!/bin/bash

sentence="this is a sentence"
IFS=" " read -a words <<< "$sentence"
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

In bash, `read -a` will divide a string by `$IFS` and place the divided parts into elements of the array.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays for more information about how bash arrays work.

If you want more details in pursuit of a specific problem, you might want to tell us what the problem is, or risk making this an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Well my "problem" was not understanding why one syntax ran how I expected and another one that seemed equivalent to me did not work. An answer like yours is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting turns any string into a single unit. If you lose the quotes, everything should be fine.