# Is increment/decrement operators Undefined Behaviour in Bash?

Tags: c, linux, bash, posix, post-increment

In standards C99 and C11 an expression like the following is U.B. (Undefined Behaviour):

```
 int x = 2;
 int ans = x++  +  x++;
```

In Bash the increment/decrement operators are defined and the official document in [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) says that the conventions of standard C are followed.

In addition, Bash is mostly POSIX conforming and in its standard document (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) is said that, for arithmetical operations, C standard is assumed unless the contrary is said.

Since I cannot find more information, my conclusion is that in Bash we also have Undefined Behaviour with increment operators:

```
x = 2
echo $(( x++ + x++ ))
```

I need to be sure if my conclusion is right or, on the contrary, if there exists some convention in Bash that supersedes the C standard.

**Additional note:** Trying in my system (Ubuntu 14.04, Bash version 4.3.11) it seems that left to right evaluation is performed, with an increment that is immediately done where the operator `++` appears.

Comment: Whatever `$(( x++ + x++ ))` is supposed to mean, I guarantee there's a clearer and safer way to express the intent.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I interested in knowing the rules of Bash in aritmethical expansions. Is portable code? I am trying to understand the Bash formal specifications.

Comment: Bash doesn't have formal specifications. I'm not implying this question is a duplicate, because it's specific to arithmetic evaluation; however, in a more general sense [this has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23207168/418413).

Comment: @kojiro: In the link you provided, under the title **Order of evaluation**, your answer says `Bash interprets expressions in its primary syntax from left to right`. Is that opinion based on section 3.7.1. of [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)?

Comment: The only way this question is at all meaningful is if you have to process untrusted arithmetic expressions via the shell arithmetic evaluator and you want to know if UB can result. Otherwise, as Keith and Martin have stated, it's rubbish/unsafe/nonsense code.

Comment: @R.: The "rubbish" code is there only to make the question easy to expose. I am trying to understand how Bash process arithmetical expressions. Maybe I wasn't clear on that point. I'll never would have to compute something like `x++ + x++`.

Comment: @pablo1977: Any expression where the answer to this question matters is equally "rubbish code".

Comment: @R..: Nevertheless, it's a valid question. It's useful to know the rules (if there are any).

Comment: @pablo1977 well, I think I got it from the manual, but sure, that reference will do as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be seeking to find a defined standard for bash, as there is for C. Unfortunately, there isn't one.

There are really only two guides:

1. [Volume 3 (Shell and Utilities)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_title.html) of the Open Group Base Specifications, commonly known as "Posix", which is deliberately underspecified. It does state that arithmetic evaluation "be equivalent to that described in Section 6.5, Expressions, of the ISO C standard," but that standard does not specify any value for an expression which contains both a mutator and another use of the same variable (such as `x + x++` or `x++ + x++`).
2. The actual behaviour of and manual for a *particular version* of bash, neither of which qualify as a formal specification, and neither of which are in any way certified or blessed by any standards organization.

Consequently, I would have to say that no document defines the result in bash of arithmetic evaluation of an expression like `x++ + x++`. Even if the bash manual for the current bash version specified it (which it doesn't), and even if it were possible to deduce the behaviour from examination of the source code of the current bash version (which it is, but not necessarily easily), that would not be in any sense of the word a formal specification.

That makes the result "undefined" in the intuitive sense of the word: no result is defined.

There is certainly no law requiring that every programming language be fully specified, and many are not. Indeed, while C and C++ both enjoy exhaustive definitions in the form of ISO standards, there are many usages which the standards deliberately do not define, partly because doing so would require forms of error-detection which would impede performance. These decisions have been and will continue to be controversial, and I have no intention of taking sides.

I will simply observe that in the context of a formal specification, the following are *not* the same:

- The requirement that the result of evaluating a particular program construct *be detected as an error*.
- The explicit statement that the value of a particular construct is *implementation-defined*.
- The failure to specify the value of a particular construct, or the explicit statement that it is unspecified.
- The explicit statement that the result of evaluating a particular construct is *undefined*.

The first two of these are definitely formal specifications, in that they imply that the result of an evaluation is well-defined (in the second case, the definition should/must appear in the implementation manual). Such constructs are definitely usable, although of course the implementation-specific constructs will render the program non-portable.

The third does not accurately define the value of the construct it describes, although it will often provide a list of possibilities. The fourth, which is a C/C++ specialty, specifies that the construct is not valid and that it is the programmer's responsibility to avoid it because the standard imposes *no requirements whatsoever* on an implementation. Such constructs should never be used.

Examples of the four cases taken from specific specifications:

- Error detection. (Java) "if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown."
- Implementation-specific. (Posix shell) "Open files are represented by decimal numbers starting with zero. *The largest possible value is implementation-defined*; however, all implementations shall support at least 0 to 9, inclusive, for use by the application."
- Unspecified behaviour. (C/C++) "An example of unspecified behavior is the order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated." (from the definitions section of the C99 standard).
- Undefined behaviour (C) "In both operations [<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>%</kbd>], if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined." (Contrast with Java, above.)

The last two categories seem to trigger a kind of outrage amongst certain programmers; disbelief that it is possible that a specification leave behaviour unspecified, and even that the absence of a specification is some kind of conspiracy to hide the truth (which must, therefore, be set free). And this in turn leads to random experimentation with particular language implementations, which must be futile precisely because the standard does not bind all implementations to do the same thing, or even for a particular implementation to consistently do the same thing.

It's also important to avoid thinking of "undefined behaviour" as a specific behaviour. If a computation with UB had a specific behaviour, it wouldn't be *undefined*. Even if the computation had a range of possible specific behaviours, it would be merely unspecified.

"Undefined behaviour" is not a specification or an attribute. You cannot detect "undefined behaviour" because the lack of definition means that any behaviour is possible, including behaviour which is the defined result of some other construct.

In particular, "undefined behaviour" is *not* the same as a detected error because the implementation is under no obligation to detect it.

Comment: So, in your opinion, in relation to side effects in arithmetical operations, one would have to consider that Bash inherits the "undefined behaviour" attribute from ISO C, unless the contrary is said. Right?

Comment: @pablo1977: It is clear that Posix does not specify evaluation order of arithmetic expressions, and that Posix does not constrain arithmetic evaluation to assign variables during the evaluation (it merely requires them to be assigned "after the expansion"). To the extent that bash attempts to be a Posix-compliant shell, it inherits the lack of specificity. The only guide given is that the result be "equivalent" to that of standard C/6.5, which indeed specifies that `i + i++` is undefined (as well as `i++ + i++`). What is equivalent to undefined behaviour? I'd say that it is indeed undefined.

Comment: @pablo1977: But having said that, "undefined behaviour" is not an attribute. It is a statement that the behaviour is undefined, nothing more. You cannot detect "undefined behaviour" because the lack of definition means that any behaviour is possible, including behaviour which is the defined result of some other construct.

Comment: Sorry by using the term "attribute", I didn't know how to express it better. Your comment (all that about Posix) in response to my own comment here maybe would have been part of your answer, because it's the specific conclusion that I was looking for in the main question.

Comment: @pablo1977: I added the Posix quote to my answer. My point is, in general, that it is misleading (though common) to say that the C/C++ standard "specifies that the result of [something] is Undefined Behaviour," because that tends to reify UB. It would be a lot better to say that the C/C++ standard "does not define the consequences of [something], allowing *any behaviour* to result".

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the bash code (bash 4.3), source **expr.c**, I see the following:

```
      /* post-increment or post-decrement */
      if (stok == POSTINC || stok == POSTDEC)
        {
          /* restore certain portions of EC */
          tokstr = ec.tokstr;
          noeval = ec.noeval;
          curlval = ec.lval;
          lasttok = STR;    /* ec.curtok */

          v2 = val + ((stok == POSTINC) ? 1 : -1);
          vincdec = itos (v2);
          if (noeval == 0)
        {
#if defined (ARRAY_VARS)
          if (curlval.ind != -1)
            expr_bind_array_element (curlval.tokstr, curlval.ind, vincdec);
          else
#endif
            expr_bind_variable (tokstr, vincdec);
        }
          free (vincdec);
          curtok = NUM; /* make sure x++=7 is flagged as an error */
        }
```

As you can see, the post increment is not implemented with the C post-increment:

```
v2 = val + ((stok == POSTINC) ? 1 : -1);
```

IMHO, with that code, and the fact that a line is processed token by token from left to right, I could say the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but isn't that dependent on the way chosen to implement Bash? In future versions people could change the implementation. On the other hand, what you said about the left-to-right order of token processing is a good point.

Comment: @pablo1977 I don't understand the significance of pointing out the dependence on implementation. It seems tautological. While there isn't an international standard for bash (as opposed to XCU), bash usually follows or extends existing standards for `sh` in POSIX, IEEE and their extensions. In this case, see _Operands_ [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_02_01). What I'm trying to say is it seems highly unlikely that anyone will change bash in a way that breaks this behavior.

Comment: It's not so much the setting of `v2` as it is the variable being rebound to the new value _when it's evaluated_ (the call to `expr_bind_variable`). This happens with `PREINC` and `PREDEC` as well. In C, the `++` bit can be deferred but that's not the case in `bash`, so this answer is correct. In any case, the "standard" for `bash` is the actual source code :-)

Comment: @kojiro: So, in your opinion, do I have to accept the answer of j.a.? All of you agree with him, so it seems the right answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Posix says "All changes to variables in an arithmetic expression shall be in effect after the arithmetic expansion", which is roughly the same as the C standard; i.e. it allows the actual modification to be deferred until after the evaluation of the entire expression. In fact, the current implementation of bash does not defer the assignment, but I don't see how that binds future versions of bash (or, for that matter, any Posix shell).

Comment: @pablo1977 I wouldn't presume to tell you which answer you think is best. In particular, a _correct_ answer may not be the _best_ answer. My comment was to express confusion about your comment. I realize you are looking for a formal spec-based answer, and this answer is implementation based, so I guess the biggest _gap_ (if you want to call it that) in this answer is that it doesn't explicitly state that bash has no spec.

Comment: Either case and following what the question says about bash documentation, if it follows C/C++ documentation, even in case it does not follow the c/c++ counterpart operator, it can depend on the bash version being in use and can be different implemented from version to version of bash.  I would assume the result is undefined behaviour and try to express it otherwise.  What does actually mean x++ + x++ ???????