# building a customized shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am building a shell using C in Minix. This is a Homework for my 'Operating System Lab'. The idea is to build a bash like shell( with fork() and exec()) which will have it's own environment path, some additional functions etc. ( And Of course I will be running it using bash.)

So now in My case I am new to shell. What are basic features that users use most in bash. I do not need the advance features. All I want to know is that What type basic implementation should be include in a shell.

NB. I am not asking for any code. No need to post any link of the big resources. Share your idea, explanation or suggestion. If you have any tutorial link regarding this, you can share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see the [semantics for bash scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23207168/418413) thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum functionality for a shell:

- Spawn a process for the user.
- Accept input from user on behalf of a running process.  Relay output from a running process to the user.
- Keep a list of directories that the shell will look through to find the process the user wishes to execute (i.e., the PATH variable for most other shells).  Allow the user to view and modify this directory inventory.
- Provide a mechanism to terminate the running process.

Comment: A big thanks for your comment ... (y) . Perfectly,  what I wanted.